# Explode a Polars column with dictionary entries into subcolumns

Tags: pandas, python-polars

I have a Polars dataframe in the following format.

[image]

I want to explode the Price and Duration column so that **idxmax** and **max** become subcolumns.

[image]

What set of method chaining must I perform on the dataframe or columns to achieve such a transformation? Is it possible to expand dictionaries as subcolumns? If the chaining is too complicated, would it be simpler to convert the Polars dataframe to a Pandas dataframe, then expand every dictionary row?

Comment: struct columns are polars's closest analog to pandas's multiindex columns. You can operate on the struct columns like [this](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.struct.field.html#polars.Expr.struct.field)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "dict" columns are `pl.Struct` dtypes (I believe polars will convert automatically on most `df` creations, if not try a `cast`?), you can [`unnest`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest) those columns.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'location' : ['new york'], 'price' : [{'idxmax' : [3, 4, 1], 'max' : 32.43}]})
```

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌──────────┬───────────────────┐
│ location ┆ price             │
│ ---      ┆ ---               │
│ str      ┆ struct[2]         │
╞══════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ new york ┆ {[3, 4, 1],32.43} │
└──────────┴───────────────────┘
```

```py
df.unnest('price')
```

```
shape: (1, 3)
┌──────────┬───────────┬───────┐
│ location ┆ idxmax    ┆ max   │
│ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---   │
│ str      ┆ list[i64] ┆ f64   │
╞══════════╪═══════════╪═══════╡
│ new york ┆ [3, 4, 1] ┆ 32.43 │
└──────────┴───────────┴───────┘
```

EDIT: I see what you mean by "subcolumns" with "Price" then "idxmax" etc., that isn't possible as far as I know but you can always rename the new columns "price_idxmax" or something if you really need that preserved in some way. Another option would be to keep the `struct` column and reference the "subcolumns" like so:

`pl.col('price').struct.field('idxmax')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cannot name the 'subcolumns' to something like 'price_idxmax' or 'price_max', because the data would be piped to another function that expects subcolumns for the 'Price' and 'Duration' columns. Would it be easier to convert the Polars dataframe to a Pandas dataframe, then apply unnest to each row of dictionary?

Comment: @disguisedtoast If your other function expects the input to be a pandas df with a multiindex column then it's not a question of being easier, it simply must be pandas in that case. This really seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)